# Dynamic username in AWS Inline policy

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

Im trying to dynamically refer username to AWS IAM identity center's inline policy. I was following the other SO's posts, but it still don't work.

My goal is to login to vm by command

> aws ec2-instance-connect ssh --instance-id xxx --os-user xxx

to added vm's user.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEqual": {
                "ec2:osuser": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::11111111:user/${aws:username}"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

Static assignment of ec2:osuser works just fine.

> "ec2:osuser": "xxxxx"

My AWS account has 2 assigned user provisioned from azure. Am I assuming correctly that ${aws:username} should be Username of these two account?

Comment: See the table of [principal key values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-infotouse).

Comment: So what's wrong in this policy?

Comment: I shared that table because it explains when `aws:username` will be present and what it represents. That said, I don't see any scenario in which `arn:aws:iam::11111111:user/${aws:username}` is going to have the same value as `ec2:osuser`. Did you mean to simply compare against `${aws:username}`, not the full IAM user ARN?